# Fermat's Little Theorem True or False

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

1. 2^12 ≡ 1 mod 13
   By Fermat’s Little Theorem, I know that this is true. But how do I write a proof for this?
2. 2^14 ≡ 1 mod 15
   Fermat's Little Theorem works only when p is a prime number and we have mod p and power p-1. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Hint: $2^{12} = 4096$.  You don’t need to write out an abstract proof for a single calculation.

Comment: $2^6=64=(5\times 13)-1 \equiv -1 \bmod 13$. $2^{12}=(2^6)^2 \equiv (-1)^2=1 \bmod 13$.  $2^4=16 \equiv 1 \bmod 15$. $2^{12}=(2^4)^3 \equiv (1)^3=1 \bmod 15$. $2^{14}=2\times 2\times 2^{12}\equiv 4 \bmod 15$

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compute the remainders;
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^{12}&=&4096&=&315\times13+1.\\
2^{14}&=&16384&=&1092\times15+4.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

1. $$ 2^{12} \equiv 1 (\mod13) \Rightarrow 13 \mid 2^{12} - 1 \\ 2^{12} - 1 = (2^6 +1)(2^6 -1) = 65 \cdot 63 \\ 65 = 13 \cdot 5$$
2. You can easily compute the last digit and see it won't be divisible by 5.

Answer (score 1):

> 2^12 ≡ 1 mod 13 By Fermat’s Little Theorem, I know that this is true. But how do I write a proof for this?

You point out that $13$ is prime and  $13\not \mid 2$ so by FLT $2^{13-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$.  That's all you have to say.  Set up the conditions for FLT and the Theorem takes care of the rest.

> 2^14 ≡ 1 mod 15 Fermat's Little Theorem works only when p is a prime number and we have mod p and power p-1. Am I missing anything here?

Not really.  You can't use FLT because $15$ is not prime.  So it doesn't have to be true.  It *might* be true but in doesn't have to be true.

And You can show it *isn't* true by noticing that $2^4=16\equiv 1 \pmod{15}$.  So $2^{12} =(2^4)^3 \equiv 1^3 \equiv 1\pmod{15}$.  And so $2^{14}=2^{12}\cdot 2^2\equiv 1\cdot 2^2\equiv 4 \pmod {15}$.

Or if you know the Eulers Thereom you can show it is not true:  $\phi(15)=\phi(3)\phi(5)=2\cdot 4=8$ and so $2^{8}\equiv 1$ and $2^{14}\equiv 2^8\cdot 2^6\equiv 1\cdot 64\equiv 4\pmod {15}$.

Or if you know Chinese Remainder Theorem you can show $2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so $2^{14}=(2^2)^7\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $2^4\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ (both by FLT) so $2^{14}\equiv (2^4)^2 \cdot 2^2 \equiv 1\cdot 4\pmod 5$ so we must combine $1\equiv 4 \pmod 3$ and $4\pmod 5$ to get $4\pmod {15}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof of $1$) is essentially done. For full pedantry points you'll want to explicitly state everything:

- Since $13$ is prime, by Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^{13} \equiv 2\pmod{13}$. Therefore $2^{12} \equiv 1\pmod{13}$.

Or:

- *Theorem $1$:  If $p$ is a prime number, then for any integer $a$,*
  $$a^p \equiv a \pmod p$$
  Let $a = 2, p = 13$. Then by Theorem $1$, $2^{13} \equiv 2 \pmod {13}$ and therefore $2^{12} \equiv 1\pmod{13}$.

---

In question $2$), $15$ is not prime and therefore you cannot use FLT. You appear close to making a [converse error$^{*}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent). Fleablood's and Servaes' direct computations are enough to show it is false.

$^{*}$*Note:* Just because $15$ is composite does not mean that $2^{15} \not\equiv 1\pmod{15}$. [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) , like $561$, are composite numbers $n$ that satisfy the FLT-like equivalence relation $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {n}$ for all integers $b$ that are relatively prime to $n$.